# How could I get the number of items in a dynamic list with Sass?

Tags: html, sass

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  ...
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to get the 'n' value o the last item of a dinamic list with Sass? 
Like counting the number of items within the 'ul' using the @each or @for statements ?

Comment: why not use javascript ?

Comment: Might be better to ask what you want to achieve, instead of asking how to do it with a particular solution

Comment: What I want to do is move a div off the screen like
    
   top: -(heightOfListItem * numListItems)

Answer (score 7):

No.  Sass **only** compiles to CSS.  It is never sent to the browser.  It has no knowledge of the DOM.

Comment: I thought that...I know it could be easily done with some Javascript but i'm trying to do it all in Sass

Comment: Well you can't.  Sass is not a scripting language for the browser.  It can only be used to programatically generate CSS.  That's it.